# How to prevent Durandal to (re)load a page on startup?

Tags: javascript, url-routing, durandal

Let's say I use *standard SPA project with Durandal*. Routing is with **pushState: true**. 
And everything goes great.

However.

I want to generate the page fully prepared (i.e., generated on server (for instance, ASP.NET MVC)) (*for SEO optimization*, as well as to minimize traffic). I.e., ***the page generation is not a thing here***: I just use server routing and generating appropriate page -- not a question.
(for instance, 'mydomain.com/about/' page).

And *everything goes great **so far** as well*.

But.

Now, when the page is loaded, **Durandal** obviously **recognizes** the 'about' page and **starts loading it from server *again*** (in case of caching, it does not, but if I need actual data, my services would still go to get the data, which is additional request+time).

So, the question is how I can **prevent that reloading** and ***simply bind the ViewModel to already existing HTML*** (which already rendered on server and is a part of currently loaded page)?

*(just to clarify it one more time: the main thing is to prevent duplicate loading of the page on startup)*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try customising the `viewEngine`; specifically, the `createView` method.

Effectively, you'd have to pre-check to see if your view is already loaded, then return a deferred promise which resolves your view; otherwise, return the default from `createView`. Something along these lines:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "durandal/viewEngine"
],
function($, viewEngine) {
    var defaultCreateView = viewEngine.createView;

    viewEngine.createView = function(viewId) {
        if (viewId == "about") {
            // Some jQuery expression to find your view
            var $about = $("#about");

            // Emulate what createView would have done when the view was loaded
            $about.setAttribute("data-view", viewId)

            // Return the view element as a resolved promise
            return $.when($about);
        }

        // View is not loaded - defer to default createView implementation.
        return defaultCreateView.call(this, viewId);
    };
});
```